# svn:ignore does not work as expected

Tags: svn, svnignore

I'm trying to pull together a testcase for another problem I have and for this I want to mimic a svn repository with a directory in svn:ignore.
When that value is set, the directory specified in the value is excluded from version controll? right?

below an outline of what I've done. And the results i got. I'm a kind of mystified, hopefully somebody here can help me.

```
[/tmp]$svn --version
svn, version 1.6.15 (r1038135)
  compiled Nov 29 2010, 16:11:54

[/tmp]$mkdir svnadmin
[/tmp]$cd svnadmin/
[/tmp/svnadmin]$svnadmin create ignoretest
[/tmp/svnadmin]$mkdir ../client
[/tmp/svnadmin]$cd ../client
[/tmp/client]$svn co file:///tmp/svnadmin/ignoretest
Checked out revision 0.
[/tmp/client]$cd ignoretest/
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$svn propset svn:ignore private .
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$svn propget svn:ignore
private

[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$svn ci -m "ignore set"
Sending        .
```

Not sure whether I have to do the commit here, in my understanding svn:ignore is a global recognized parameter setting it here means it is set for the central repository?

```
Committed revision 1.
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$mkdir private
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$echo 'secret' > private/file1.txt
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$svn add *
A         private
A         private/file1.txt
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$svn ci -m "something wrong?"
Adding         private
Adding         private/file1.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 2.
```

This does raise a red flag wih me

```
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$mkdir ../../client2
[/tmp/client/ignoretest]$cd ../../client2
[/tmp/client2]$svn co file:///tmp/svnadmin/ignoretest
A    ignoretest/private
A    ignoretest/private/file1.txt
```

It is really checked in.

```
 U   ignoretest
Checked out revision 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the ignore property doesn't actually prevent you from adding files to the repository. It just stops svn from reporting those filenames when you run "svn status".

If you'd run "svn status" after setting the ignore property you'd notice that "private" wasn't displayed. However, there was nothing stopping you explicitly adding and committing it, as you did with "svn add *".

Comment: I find that hard to believe, aren't you confused with global-ignore? from the svn-redbook: svn:ignore

The svn:ignore property contains a list of file patterns which certain Subversion operations will ignore. Perhaps the most commonly used special property, it works in conjunction with the global-ignores run-time configuration option (see the section called “Config”) to filter unversioned files and directories out of commands svn status, svn add, and svn import.

Comment: See the note at the bottom of this page: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Answer (score 1):

I think your use of `svn add *` is the one giving you unexpected results. The shell usually expands the `*` to all files and will include ignored ones. Effectively, the svn:ignore was, well, ignored. I think you are better off using `svn add –force .`

Comment: but is there a way to really keep directories or files out of the repo regardless of the '\*'? would propset private/\* . be a better match than?

Comment: @dr jerry - the shell extension of `*` is independent of SVN and hence also not aware of `svn:ignore`. That is why I suggested that you use `svn add -force .`. Otherwise use something like TortoiseSVN which makes this all more intuitive and also protects you from adding folders you don't really need.